# Convert object to url query parameters

Tags: javascript, angular, http, url-parameters

What is the equivalent of [`$httpParamSerializer(params)`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/DefaultUrlSerializer-class.html) from angular 1 in angular 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about an exact equivalent, but with [`URLSearchParams`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/URLSearchParams-class.html) it will handle the encoding for you. Sucks it doesn't allow you to just pass an object, so you need to do something like

```
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';

let params = new URLSearchParams();
for (let key in someObj) {
  if (somObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    params.set(key, someObj[key])
  }
}
```

If all you need is the string for some odd reason, just call `params.toString()`. Otherwise if you want to pass it to the `Http` request, just do

```
let options = new RequestOptions({ search: params });
http.get(url, options);
```

The query string will get appended to the URL in a GET request, and in a POST request, you can set it as the body

```
http.post(url, params);
```